# An extension of the axiom of choice needed?

Tags: set-theory

Given a set $\mathscr F$ of nonempty sets. Is it possible to define the set of all choice functions on $\mathscr F$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set of all choice functions on $\mathscr F$ is just the product
$$\prod_{X \in \mathscr F} X$$

You don't need the axiom of choice to define it. The axiom of choice only states that (if all elements of $\mathscr F$ are nonempty) it is nonempty.

Comment: Nice and clear!